# How to create a program from the program's code rather than from it's filename

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

Using the typescript compiler api I can easily create a `Program` with

```js
let program = ts.createProgram([file], {});
```

where file is the filename, but is there a way to do this with the actual code instead?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to provide a custom `ts.CompilerHost`. On that interface you can provide a `getSourceFile` method that provides a source file with the text you want.

Doing this is a lot of work though. It might be faster to use [ts-morph/bootstrap](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/tree/latest/packages/bootstrap) which will handle a lot of this for you.